# Cyclic Voltammogram - How to determine Overpotential

Tags: electrochemistry

http://youtu.be/1f92vGOridg

Clicking on the link above will take you to a video with a diagram of a voltammogram.

Through my own experiments I have managed to obtain a similar diagram. However, I am unclear on how to determine the overpotential from such a diagram.

I know that the overpotential is simply the potential required over and above the amount required to get the reaction going thermodynamically.

If you could, please be explicit about what points I should choose exactly to make my calculation.

Thank you !